# How to programmatically close an open file/application in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, powershell, mfc

I am writing data to a csv file as result of operation. Than I open the file in excel to examine the data. Often time I forget to close the file in excel and the next operation can't write to the same file. It looks very difficult if not impossible but is there a way I can programmatically close the file (=application that is using the file) before I write to it?

I guess the first thing will be to determine which application is using the file and then shutdown that app? Maybe someone has written a class for this or something?

Comment: Why not just flag the file as ReadOnly in the first operation, before it's opened in Excel.  That will prevent Excel from getting an opportunistic lock on it.  You can still write data to it in subsequent operations by removing the RO attribute, or using the -Force switch.

Comment: @mjolinor Good idea, Let me try that!

Comment: @mjolinor That was brilliant! If you want to post this as answer I will accept it. It did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, per the comments:

Flag the file as ReadOnly in the first operation.  Then you can launch Excel and prevent it from getting an opportunistic lock on the file. You can still update the file in subsequent operations by either removing the RO attribute, or using the -Force switch when you write the updates.